# R error because of ~ symbol in my Windows User name?

Tags: r, unicode, path, symbols

I am pretty new to R and since I got a new laptop, I'm constantly getting this error:

- Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1

and

- In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Jo�o/Documents": The system cannot find the path specified

One thing I looked up is that R has trouble reading symbols such as ~ (my username contains it).
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: it's not because of the ~ but because of the bug in Unicode handling. That said, home folder with non-ASCII characters is usually a bad idea, because there are so many buggy apps out there

Comment: I appreciate the insight. What would be a suitable solution then? I even tried to create a new User, but the error still persists after changing the working directory.

Comment: What version of R are you using? Version 4.2 should have much better support for Unicode on Windows. When exactly does that error occur? Does it happen when you open R? What does `traceback()` show after the error?

Comment: @MrFlick it happens precisely the moment I open R. The second error message shows up immediately 4x times and a pop-up with the first message follows right after. I am using the latest version of R and the code traceback() says: No traceback available

Comment: Please confirm the exact R version number. Are you using the R GUI or RStudio? Did you try running `traceback()` in R after the error? What was the output?